# How to select the first increasing values from Ruby array without enumerating every value?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Imagine one has an array such as:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5]
```

And one wishes to create an array consisting of the first *n* elements, starting with the first element in the array, that are a monotonic sequence increasing by one. Given `a` above, that array would be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

One could use `slice_when`, such as:

```
a.slice_when { |a, b| a != b - 1 }.first
```

The drawback of this approach is that `slice_when` continues to iterate over the array elements `2`, `5`, `1`, and so on, until the end. In this case, iterating over the remaining values is useless, since one really just wants the first slice.

What is the elegant way to express this in Ruby, that ceases iterating once the first increasing sequence is selected?

Comment: Writing your own method *maybe*?

Comment: To be clear, `n` is not specified, the monotonic sequence can have as few as two elements. Correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is correct.

Comment: If the array is `[2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1]` are you expecting to return `[2]` or `[-1, 0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: `2`, since the resulting array should start with the fist element in the main array `a`.

Comment: How about `[2, 4, 5, 7]` - what is correct result?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski : `[2]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about lazy evaluation?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5]
a.lazy.slice_when { |a, b| a != b - 1 }.first
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`Enumerable#lazy`

Comment: Ahhhh, `lazy`, yes, I see.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the following.

```
def stairstep(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?
  enum = arr.first.step
  arr.take_while { |x| x == enum.next }
end

stairstep [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5]   
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: undefined local variable `a'

Comment: Thanks, @sagarpandya82. I edited to put it in a method and didn't change all the `a`'s to `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5]
(a.size - 1).times { |i| break a[0..i] if a[i] > a[i + 1] }
#=> [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: I believe that should be `if a[i] != a[i+1]-1` and there's a problem when`a.size < 2`.